# bot command in discord.py REWRITE, how to conditional branch based on role contains AND role doesnt contain?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to add some if statements to the "`ready`" command, something like: "if user has any of roles A,B,C" then do stuff.  Else if user has any of roles D,E,F then do other stuff. I think if someone can help me resolve the stack trace error below then it will likely solve the Question below the code

```
import logging
import time
import discord
import asyncio
import time
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import MissingRequiredArgument

prefix = "!"
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, case_insensitive=True)

token = open("token.txt", "r").read()

class MemberRoles(commands.MemberConverter):
        async def convert(self, ctx, argument):
            member = await super().convert(ctx, argument)
            return [role.name for role in member.roles[1:]] # Remove everyone role!

@bot.command()
#i prefer not using @commands.has_any_role decorator because i want my 1 "ready" command to branch based on the role(s) the user has
#I am trying to make my bot command able to do multiple role checks
#I am trying to adapt this example "async def roles(ctx, *, member: MemberRoles):" from https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html


async def ready(ctx, *, message: str, member: MemberRoles):
    '''
    !ready must include text after the command and can only be used if you are assigned ANY of these roles: Admin, Newbie
    '''

    if message is None:
        return
    else:
        try:
          #stuff
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))

#This part, about detecting which roles a member has does not work, see the question below the code for more information
    await ctx.send('I see the following roles: ' + ', '.join(member))


@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.channel.send("Cannot ready without a message.  Type !ready <your message> and try again.")
    else:
        raise error

bot.run(token)
```

I think if someone can help me resolve this stack trace error then i can address the "question" below. The **stack trace** error complains at the "`raise error`" point. The error i see is "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: ready() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'member'"

**Question:** Assuming that the  "MemberRoles" class is a good way to do this, how do I use it within my "ready" command to achieve the A,B,C and D,E,F   IF Else branching that I require?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one keyword only argument in a command, because [discord.py](/questions/tagged/discord.py) uses keyword only arguments [to collect the end of a message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#keyword-only-arguments).  You actually just want the authors roles, so you don't need to use a converter at all:

```
@bot.command
async def ready(ctx, *, message: str):
    author_roles = ctx.author.roles
    ...
```

As to checking roles, you can do something like

```
roles_one = {"A", "B", "B"}
roles_two = {"D", "E", "F"}
if any(role.name in roles_one for role in author_roles):
    ...
elif not any(role.name in roles_two for role in author_roles):
    ...
```

Comment: hey Patrick, what if I dont want them to type  "!ready @member This is a message" . 
 Instead I want them typing "!ready This is a message".  I still need the command itself to recognize the user who invoked "ready" and it must be able to conditionally branch based on If Invoker's role contains A,B,C and Else If Invoker's role doesnt contain D,E,F.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @PeterNoges See the edit I just made.  You can use `ctx.author.roles` directly